# How to get differences between previous node and written/updated node in a Firebase Realtime Database Triggers cloud fuunction

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firebase Cloud functions.

```
exports.savePreviousDataTriggers = functions.database.ref('/interestingNode')
.onWrite(event => {

    // do stuff
})
```

With `event.data.val();` I can get the whole `interestingNode` node

How about get only **the edited child nodes** ?

My aim is to get **only** the new/updated values and NOT the whole `interestingNode`.

Just the differences between the previous node and the new one updated/writte.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily get updates from a lower level in the tree, by changing the path that you trigger on:

```
exports.savePreviousDataTriggers = functions.database.ref('/interestingNode/{nodeId}')
.onWrite(event => {

    // do stuff
})
```

With this your code will get triggered for each specific child node that gets written (created, updated, or deleted).